# Is the set of Riemannian metrics with Partially Hyperbolic geodesic flow path connected?

Tags: metric-spaces, riemannian-geometry, dynamical-systems

Fix a compact connected smooth manifold M. Denote by $PH(M)$ the set of Riemannian metrics $g$ of $M$ such that the geodesic flow $g_t$, given by

$$
g^t:T^1M\rightarrow T^1M$$

$$v\mapsto \gamma_v'(t),$$
where $\gamma_v(t)$ is the only geodesic with $\gamma_v(0)=\pi(v)$ and $\gamma_v'(0)=v$, is partially hyperbolic. By partially hyperbolic I mean that there exist constants $c>0$, $0<\lambda<1$ and a continuous non-trivial $Dg^t-$invariant splitting of $TT^1M=E^s\oplus <X> \oplus E^c\oplus E^u$ such that

1. $\|D_x g^t\cdot v\|\leq c\lambda^t\|v\|$, for $v\in E^s$ and all $t>0$;

2)$\|D_x g^t\cdot v\|\leq c\lambda^{t}\|v\|$, for $v\in E^u$ and all $t>0$;

3. $c\lambda^t\|v\|\leq\|D_xg^t\cdot v\|\leq c\lambda^{-t}\|v\|$, for $v\in E^c$ and all $t>0$.

For instance, all Anosov flows are partially hyperbolic flows, so $PH(M)$ contains all negatively curved metrics.

**Questions:** 1) Given two metrics $g_0, g_1\in PH(M)$ is there a continuous path $\alpha:[0,1]\rightarrow PH(M)$ such that $\alpha(0)=g_0$ and $\alpha(1)=g_1$?

2. More specifically we could ask $PH(M)$ is convex, i.e., the path $\alpha(t)=(1-t)g_0+tg_1$ is fully contained in $PH(M)$.

I believe the answer may be positive because it seems to me that we can not break the partially hyperbolic structure in a continuous way.

Comment: Your belief does not seem to be based on anything. My best guess is that this space is disconnected. But proving this would be a hard task with no reward since I do not see any applications of disconnectedness.

Comment: @MoisheKohan you are absolutely right. It is just a wild guess.

Comment: I may be missing something, but aren't all metrics on $M$ partially hyperbolic under this definition? Just let $E^c$ be all of $TT^1M$ and let $1/\lambda$ be larger than the maximum of the norms $||D_x g^t||$ for $x \in T^1M$ and $t \in [-1, 1]$.

Comment: Sorry, @mollyerin forgot to say that $E^s$ and $E^u$ are non-trivial. I will add this in my post.